# How do you repeatedly click two buttons when you have to wait for the second button to appear?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a simple script that loops through all elements on a page and shares them in vanilla JavaScript. Here is what I have so far

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('share-gray-large');
for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].click();
    document.getElementsByClassName('internal-share__link')[0].click();
}
```

The `share-gray-large` button is the  class of the "share" buttons. Once the first share button is clicked, a modal appears that asks the user where they want to share the items to. I need to click the first item in the modal with class name `internal-share__link`. The problem that I am running up against is the fact that the last line of my code results in the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

which makes sense, as the modal hasn't appeared yet at the time of the second `click()` function being called. I need to wait for the element to appear, then click it, then wait until the modal disappears to share the next item. I've looked into async/await functions, `setTimeout()`, and the solutions from similar StackOverflow questions. I adapted this secondary solution

```js
var waitForEl = function(className, callback) {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName(className).length) {
        callback();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            waitForEl(className, callback);
        }, 100);
    }
};

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('share-gray-large');
for(var i=0; i< buttons.length; i++){
    waitForEl('share-gray-large', function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('share-gray-large')[i].click();
    });
    waitForEl('internal-share__link', function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('internal-share__link')[0].click();
    });
}
```

which *kind of* works, but I believe that it actually ends up sharing the last item multiple times instead of sharing all of them in order. I ran into this issue of needing to wait for a button to appear as well with a different project, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

TL;DR I'm working on projects with the following sequence of steps. Using a page with 3 items that need to be shared:

1. Click "share" on first button
2. Wait for confirmation button to appear in a modal
3. Click confirm
4. Wait for modal to disappear
5. Click "share" on second button
6. Repeat steps 2-4
7. Click "share" on third button
8. Repeat steps 2-4

How do you do this in VanillaJS?

Comment: Hi! Your question looks very interesting :) To improve your question a little more, I recommend posting html code as well. Otherwise other users can't test your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer that worked for me. Credit goes to [@uingtea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082344/uingtea) for most of the solution. Since I did not post the link to the website, I was able to test it and modify their solution to suit my needs.

```js
function waitForElement(selector) {
    var element = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (element) {
        shareLinkCount--;
        element.click();

        if (shareLinkCount) { // not 0
            setTimeout(clickShareButton, 500);
        }
        else{
            element.click();
            alert('Click Finished');
        }
    } else {
        setTimeout(waitForElement, 500, selector);
    }
}

function clickShareButton() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.share-gray-large')[shareLinkCount].click();
    waitForElement('.internal-share__link');
}

var shareLinkCount = document.querySelectorAll('.share-gray-large').length - 1;


clickShareButton();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will click from the last to first share button, email share exluded and make sure the browser is allowed to click/open multiple popup.

```
function waitForElement(selector) {
    var element = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    if (element.length) {
        if (shareLinkCount == 999) { // set to real number of elements
            shareLinkCount = element.length;
        }
        shareLinkCount--;
        var shareElement = element[shareLinkCount];
        if(shareElement.textContent != "Email") // Do not click email share 
            element[shareLinkCount].click();

        if (shareLinkCount) { // not 0
            setTimeout(clickShareButton, 500);
        }
        else{
            alert('Click Finished');
            document.body.click();
        }
    } else {
        setTimeout(waitForElement, 500, selector);
    }
}

function clickShareButton() {
    var button = document.querySelector('.share-gray-large');
    button.click();
    waitForElement('internal-share__link');
}

var shareLinkCount = 999; // dummy number

clickShareButton();
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your solution! It didn't work right away, but I tweaked it and it works like a charm. The only thing is that it happens to share every other post. Do you know why this could be happening? I'll post my updated code as an answer since it's too long to post as comment

Comment: update the selector to match the post only that you want, for example `.parentClass .share-gray-large`, can you tell us what is url?

Comment: Update: I've modified the code slightly and it works perfectly. I'll post it below. A couple things to note: I wanted to decrement the things with class name `share-gray-large` and not `internal-share__link`. Also, if I call `clickShareButton()` and the `element` variable is null, it errors out on the third line because null doesn't have a length. I cleaned up the code around `shareLinkCount`, queried what I wanted to query, and fixed line 3 and it works perfectly. Thank you so much!